# Strange extra letters in i20 odometer display screen. Why?

Tags: car, lights, indicators, instrument-cluster, odometer

Sir, could you kindly find solutions from your esteemed technicians to fix this extra letters on the ODOMETER DISPLAY screen in i20 2011 1.2 p India version??

It shows up as soon as key at ON regardless if engine is running or off, and later about 5 minutes, it dimmed away slowly and everything turns normal.

It's my first time in 10 years and there are no other electrical issues, etc on the car. Just that extra letters.

Awaiting positive inputs. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Hmm, what words start with "A" but what is the system language?

Comment: The letter greyed-out next to the `A` is `B`. My car has settings for two drivers, depending on which key is used to operate the car. It also has different displays, for example fuel consumption since start, and since refuel. I guess the greyed-out legend above `km` is `mi` (miles). What does the vehicle handbook say? Perhaps the display is aging and those greyed legends are visible which were not previously.

Comment: During the last 10 years, those A and B and ml are not visible, always blank as it should be according to the manual. But, the issue recently occurred just 2 days ago. Is slowly dimmed away after 5 minutes regardless if engine is running or off. Is it related to voltage bleeding or moisture etc??? I'm really disappointed.... please help me.

Comment: I can't understand your problem. The Hyundai owner's manual says you have two odometer trip meters, A and B, and that the distance can be seen in km or miles. So it says `A` or `B` so that you know which one you are looking at. Which legend fades? The `A` and `km` or the faint `B` and `mi`? Why is this is a disappointing problem? All cars age: I had to replace the instrument cluster in one car after 8 years, not because of a letter that faded, but because it went completely haywire.

Comment: The manual says only km should appear. There are no setting options to select the A or B or mi. Just km should appear. Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: If you have a model without the option of two trip counters, remember that manufacturers often fit the same part in all the models. Perhaps it is a sign of age, or the instrument connector needs disturbing to make better electrical contacts.

Comment: The physical display is a general purpose device that will be in many different models of car (and not just Hyundai models). It is cheaper to make 100,000 displays that can show both "mi" and "km" than to make three different types (one for only mi, one for only km and one for both). Something happened which caused a bit of electrical leakage to light up the "mi" display. If it fixed itself in a few minutes, just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Many modern vehicles have  trip odometers, a vehicles odometers can be set to record Miles or Kilometers. You will have to read your vehicles manual to learn how to make changes to these settings.

A - is for Trip odometer A.

B  - is for Trip odometer B.

M  - is for Miles.

Km -  is for Kilometers.

There is the main odometer that records the Kilometers (Km.) the car has traveled since the day it was new from the factory. Then there is one **or** two trip odometers labeled **A** and **B**.

Let say you Wanted to drive from Agra to  Jodhpur but you wanted to stop in Jaipur and maybe even go see your cousin in Kishangarh and when you get to Jodhpur you want to know how many Km. you drove on that trip. You could write down the main odometers reading before you start the trip and then record the  main odometers reading when you arrive, then subtract the first number from the second number and this will tell you the kilometers traveled on your trip.

**BUT** there is an easier way because you also have **trip odometers**, You set the **trip odometer A** to 0 (*Zero*) before your trip and when you arrive it will tell you how many Km. you have driven since you set it to 0. You can reset it if you wish before your return to Agra, or not.

Maybe when you get to your cousins place in Kishangarh he wants to go for a drive to Nasirabad and you want to know how many Km. you have traveled from Kishangarh to Nasirabad and back to Kishangarh. You set **trip odometer B** to 0 (zero) in Kishangarh and when you get back to Kishangarh from Nasirabad it will tell you the amount of Km. that trip took. This will also add those same Km. to **trip odometer A**, but since you know how many Km. that  trip took you can subtract that number from  **trip odometer  A** so that the Nasirabad trip Km. is not factored into the trip from Agra to Jodhpur via  Jaipur and Kishengarh.

OR maybe you want to know how many Km. you travel in a specific time period.  You can set **trip  odometer B** on the first of the month and check it on the last day of the month see how many Km. you traveled in that month.

Are you thoroughly confused?  ***The bottom line is; You have three odometers in your car, The main one that you can not alter or change and two trip odomets that you can reset anytime you like.  You can reset **trip odometers A and B** to 0 any time you want and it will not affect the main odometer that records the total Km. the car has traveled since it was new.***

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the dim "B" and "mi" segments that show up - that's related to the (highly temperature-dependent) LCD display contrast setting, and aging of the display and the flexible connection to it. If you can adjust the LCD contrast and lower it (look in the manual!), that should fix it, otherwise you'll have to live with it.